# Print Report in React (Client Side)

Tags: django, reactjs, crystal-reports

I have been stuck here for almost one month. I don't know how to achieve this one. After doing the rest task, I have to come back to this issue.

**Explanation**

Now I am doing a web app with reacts as front-end and Django as back-end that is a version upgrade from the desktop application. In the desktop application, I have done the report with crystal report and my client very likes this design. So Now client requests me to do the same design in the web app. Nightmare is coming now.

How to print report in React or Django?

My report has summary lines,group-by lines and other functions that support by crystal report, As u know, Event through these things are not the big deal in crystal report, In Web app, I have no idea for this.

1. Should I print pdf with line and box and all things design by myself? I think this would be taken very long time because I have a lot of different design reports.
2. I tried PDFMake but it does not support IE and JSPDF is I have no idea how to do for summary line and group-by line.

Is there any way to use crystal report with my tach stack? Even I use Django, I still use MSSSQL for project requirements. So I can run crystal report in the backend. Hopefully, someone would guide me to correct way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the headless browser solution? [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) is one of the options you can use. You can create a pdf report and post it on a certain URL and then ask puppeteer to take a screenshot of that URL using its screenshot API. Checkout this
[example](https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/).

Comment: I tried JsPDF and Now I am trying JsPDF AutoTable, but it's difficult to handle such kind of summary, group by case.